# How to replay soap message?

Tags: web-services, security, soap

I would like to replay soap message against my server. I've recorded a few messages and i've tampered with Timestamps, soapbodies etc and now I would like to see that my SecurityAssertions lites up like xmastrees. The deployed server will use clientcertificates and servercertifivcates for authentisation, and the whole messageflow will go encrypted with ssl. But I would still like to test the implementation with http and no authentication.

How would one do to replay a soapmessage? Is there any application around that can do this easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try soapUI.  It has quite a few capabilities for interacting with web services including creating tests for them in which you can replay messages.

Comment: @palehorse
That will probably do the trick, I do have some problems with IIS 6 complaining about HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type whenever i try to make a request, but i guess I'll figure it out.

Comment: I have used against IIS 6 with no problems but I have always generated my test harnesses within the tool.  could it be the Content-Type that you are sending causing that sort of error?  Maybe start by having the tool generate a harness and look at the differences.